# RTMPT stream ,is there any method that i can get the sessionID in the javascript client with jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp

when use rtmpt protocal, the jwplayer first post a open command to server, and the server return a sessionID
and the the client post idle/sessionID/xx
now i am wondering that is there any method that i can get the sessionID through javaScript API with jwplayer
thanks.